# Salir de ventana luego de pulsar un botón

Tags: python, tkinter

Tengo un botón que debe desplegar un texto y después cambiar el texto, acto seguido, si lo llego a presionar, se sale de la ventana.

Llegué hasta donde cambio el nombre de botón, sin embargo no puedo salir.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
root= Tk()

def hola():
    print("Bienvenidos")

    
def changeText():
    button['text'] = 'Salir'
   
    
def salida():
    root.destroy()



button=Button(root,
    text='Saludo',width="60",height="4", command=lambda:[hola(),changeText()])
button.pack()



root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cambiaste el texto del botón, pero no su comando. Lo podrías hacer en la misma función:

```
def changeText():
    button['text'] = 'Salir'
    button['command'] = salida
```